# Trying to create an active pushed button effect. How do I make my two inset box shadows blend into one?

Tags: css, sass

My question makes more sense with a picture.

[image]

```
.instagram  {
  color: #E44060;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 12px 14px 12px 14px;
  border: 2px solid #E44060;
  border-radius: 7px;
  &:visited {
    color: inherit;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: $tertiary-color;
    background-color: #E44060;
    transition: all .25s ease 0s;
  }
  &:active {
    background-color: #B2334C;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset -4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
}
```

How do I make it so the corners of the box-shadow don't overlap making the opacity 0.4? Should I try to create a button using a different method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having 2 box-shadows, you could use the "spread" feature (the 4th number after "inset").

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use boxshadow and transform to create the push button effect

```css
.button {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

.button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Instagram</button>
```